# Custom Google form HTML Upload files button

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, google-forms

I have been trying hard to implement Google forms Add Files button in my custom html Google form but still there is no success.

Can you please give a complete example with code about how we can use Google forms upload button in custom html forms?

Thanks

Comment: What did you try ? Can you show us something please

Comment: I am able to add everything like drop downs  or check boxes but is not able to find the code for add files in the source code.

Comment: Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)